# Call controller action on completion of Resque Job

Tags: ruby-on-rails, resque

I have a controller action bar in controller foo

```
class Foo < ApplicationController
  def bar
    format.js {}
  end
end
```

*bar.js.erb*

```
$('#here').append("<h1>Hello World!</h1>");
```

*Resque job*

```
class Abc 

  @queue = :my_queue
   def self.perform(id)
   company = User.find(id)
   #do something
   # call controller action on completion of Job some what like
      b = Foo.new
      b.bar
  end

end
```

Is that possible to render a view or say call controller action on completion of rescue job

Comment: the job is executed in a different process from the main process, which is responsible for the HTTP request/response cycle. One solution is store data in cache for communication between processes (such as memcached) or using Websockets.

Comment: so there is no straight forward way to get notified when the job is completed...?